# How to fix Final Cut Pro X's "Modified File" message

Tags: error, final-cut-pro

Final Cut Pro (FCP) X 10.2.3 today gave me the most unhelpful warning message in my timeline: "Modified File" - thanks Final Cut Pro! What can I do to fix this problem?

I've tried relinking the clips, Googling just lead to more questions and no solutions. Anyone have a clue?

[image: Modified File]

Comment: Do you use other software to modify or edit footage? Any guess at what might have caused the file to change from FCP's perspective? Do you have a Time Machine back-up you could restore to?

Comment: Nope, I just use FCP... And no, it's 4K footage on an external RAID, there is no time machine

Answer (score 3):

Open the finder window and find the photo.  Drag it into the timeline to replace the "Modified" image and it should reappear.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution to this.

In FCPX go to File -> Delete Generated Event Files -> Delete optimized media, restart FCPX = Voila!

That worked for me instantly. Hope you guys find it helpful too.

Comment: In response to: "Found a solution to this. In FCPX go to File -> Delete Generated Event Files -> Delete optimized media = Voila! That worked for me instantly. Thank you! I was so stressed for having worked on something for an hour, and getting this error image. Your solution fixed it right away, and my project is back to normal. :)

Answer (score 2):

Open Package library content - open folder ".fcpbundle//Transcoded Media/High Quality Media"
Find media file or alias for modified file.
Check file or alias for correct properties. In my case alias had wrong old destination. I find destination file, make alias, copy to folder above, delete wrong alias, and rename new alias. Restart FCPX and error gone.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's [Final Cut Pro X: Alert icons](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12711) support document says only:

> **Modified File** : A media file has been changed by an application other than Final Cut Pro.

Have you tried recreating the optimised media and proxy files? The following YouTube tutorials appear to suggest this for the Modified Files problem:

- [Modified File Error | Final Cut Pro X | Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umZBUYKDA0M) (Spanish narration with screen recording)
- [FCPX: Relink Missing Projects and Events from an External Hard Drive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3da2BLqPRL0)

Comment: Yes, I tried recreating the optimized media. The first youtube video is in Spanish btw... and I'm not using proxy media, though the entire project and event are stored on an external HD